# FontAwesome error in scss file

Tags: intellij-idea, sass, font-awesome

hello fellow webdevelopers,
I'm a newbie to SASS, developing with Intellij IDEA Ultimate. I copied the `font-awesome.scss` file from the `fontawesome/sass` directory to my project and I got a few errors from the IDE, mainly at constructs like this:

```
.btn, .nav-tabs {
  [class^="icon-"], 
  [class*=" icon-"] {
    /* keeps button heights with and without icons the same */
    line-height: .9em;
  }
}
```

it keeps nagging about the colon `,` as separator between `[class^="icon-"]` and `[class*=" icon-"]`.

**but** if the section looks like this

```
a [class^="icon-"],
a [class*=" icon-"] {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}
```

everything looks fine.

furthermore, in the generated `font-awesome.css` file, there are some obvious errors as `text-decoration: inherit;` is definitely no valid CSS value. Could it be that these are bugs, or am I getting something wrong here?

how should I change the syntax at the above shown `scss` file to prevent the errors?

I'd like to use the `font-awesome.scss` as I'm also planning to use SASS for the whole project and it would be cool if I could use **fontawesome** the same way.

any suggestions on this?

Comment: `text-decoration: inherit` is definitely valid.  It sounds like Intellij IDEA isn't doing syntax highlighting properly (does it understand Sass or are you just using the CSS syntax highlighter?).  I've used Intellij IDEA before when I was writing Scala and frequently ran into false positives.

Comment: If the Sass compiler isn't throwing any errors I'd ignore the errors (or find another editor).

Comment: ok, so my IDE isn't properly equipped for developing scss... or I have to find the right plugin for that at least.... but I have another error, where it's complaining about `vertical-align: initial;` and it seems that at least this, is not a valid value for the property. See @ http://www.css3.com/css-vertical-align/ or http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp - so, what's up with that?

Comment: Looks like that [bug has been reported](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/503)

Comment: thanks @steveax! didn't check the github myself before ;)

Comment: @cimmanon would you consider to post your comment as an answer so that I could mark it as solved? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample code provided is valid Sass and compiles as it should.  Your IDE is just missing the proper syntax highlighting for Sass.